# Make time measuring independent of FPS (2D C#)

Tags: c#

Lets say I'm working in a 2D plane, with a person in the bottom of my screen, and an object that moves down along the Y-axis.

The moving object has following movement code:

```
transform.position += new Vector3 (0, -1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Now, as I want to be able to modify how long it takes for the object to connect with the player, I created this, where spawnTimeDistance is our key factor:

```
  Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3(-0.50F , (spawnTimeDistance + obstacleDimensionY + pScript.playerDimensionY), -1), Quaternion.identity);
```

As can be seen, spawnTimeDistance is a place-holder for the objects Y-distance to the player. However, using this code I get great inconsistencies with my results, especially when comparing devices. I suspect this is caused by distance being FPS dependant, instead of actual time dependant.

To fix this I believe I should implement Time.deltaTime in an extended manner, but I'm insecure on how.

EDIT - spawnDistanceTime related:

```
void Start() {
   spawnTimeDistance = 4F;
}
```

and

```
Vector2 sprite_size = obstacle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.size;
        Vector2 spriteScale = obstacle.transform.localScale;
        float sizeAndScaleY = sprite_size.y * spriteScale.y;
        float obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY = (sizeAndScaleY / obstacle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.pixelsPerUnit) * 0.5F;
        obstacleDimensionY = obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY;
```

Above code, same thing for my player.

Edited the Instantiate to include the obstacleDimensions, had them removed before as I thought it would give a simpler question.

Comment: How does `spawnTimeDistance` get its value?

Comment: @helrich I currently have it set to 1 second. My speed is 4, so to set it to 1 second I set it 4 + 50% of the Y-size of both my sprites, as to get exactly 1second between the top of my player and bottom of my moving object.

Comment: can you show the `spawnTimeDistance` calculation?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen added